# Getting an error while calculating BMI coded with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting an error while running the code

```
#script to calculate the BMI of a person

print ("Enter your heights in meters")
height = float(raw_input())
print ("Enter your Weight in Kilograms")
weight = float(raw_input())

BMI = weight/(height*height)

print (BMI)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Enter your heights in meters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Project 64\Working With Python\BMI Calculator.py", line 4, in <module>
    height = float(raw_input())
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: Because you're running in Python 3, not 2.7. `raw_input` no longer exists. Change to `input()`

Comment: I have used `input()` also but still, it shows error

Comment: Please get into the habit of actually telling us what the errors _are_ rather than us having to ask you for them

Comment: **I'm getting this kind of error** 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Project 64\Working With Python\BMI Calculator.py", line 4, in <module>
    height = float(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Search for the error `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`. The code is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) only exists in Python 2.x. You should use [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) in Python 3.

Comment: I have used 'input()' also but still it shows error